# Git pulls cause duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_ all the time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, clang

While developing iOS app we keep encountering same problem - after some git pull / merge of changes we get

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_
```

linker error

for different classes. It is possible to remove this error if one deletes the source file  (say User.m if it's duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_User ) from "Compile sources tab in targets/ Build Phases)..

The full error looks like this:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GridView in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bjpymtdfvzxkembjocjjpbswfoul/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GridView-9FDDD336172B4A48.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GridView in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bjpymtdfvzxkembjocjjpbswfoul/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GridView-9FDDD336172B4A48.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_User in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bjpymtdfvzxkembjocjjpbswfoul/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/armv7/User.o
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bjpymtdfvzxkembjocjjpbswfoul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a(User.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_User in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bjpymtdfvzxkembjocjjpbswfoul/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/armv7/User.o
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bjpymtdfvzxkembjocjjpbswfoul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a(User.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few things to try:

1. Check your project and see if you have the same file imported from two different locations. Look at your **Project | Targets | Build Phases (tab) | Compile Sources** section again and make sure the files (GridView.m and User.m) don't appear twice. That list sorts the files by date added, not filename, so you may have missed it.
2. Also, it looks like you're statically linking in an external library, libRestKit.a. Are you or someone else on your team importing the source for RESTKit as well as the static library? If you have both, you'll get duplicate symbols.
3. Finally, make sure nobody imported a .m file with something like #import "User.m" or #import "GridView.m" somewhere in the code--though that one seems less likely since you're able to resolve the problem by removing the offending source file.

You'll continue to get these issues until everyone has the same build configuration so you should have everyone commit and check in all their code. Fix any merge conflicts and get your local repo to be exactly what it ought to be on your system and then push. Then, have the rest of the team delete their repos and do a fresh clone. Hopefully having everyone start from the same code base/project will eliminate the problem from occurring again and maybe even point to where the problem occurred so you can avoid it in the future.

Best regards.

Comment: Had the same file in build phases after merging :/